# Can't find run in eclipse context menu to run my spring mvc project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc

I'm working on a spring mvc project I generate my project using maven command line and convert it to an eclipse project when I imported him on eclipse I can't find Run with Tomcat in my menu this is the screenshot of my eclipse :

[image]

Thank you for any helpe

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to execute the Maven command in eclipse, try the `Run As -> 2 Maven build...` option and input your task.

Comment: Thank you the probleme was that maven can't download all dependecies include the war plugin and eclipse didn't show it , that's way I had this problem